# SAPUI5 personalization block not working

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a block inside a page.

Now, I need to provide p13n dialog. For this, I have used this code:

```
    <smartTable:customData>
        <core:CustomData key="p13nDialogSettings" value='\{"columns":\{"visible": true \},"filter":\{"visible": false\}\}'/>
    </smartTable:customData>
```

Moreover, I have given this tag for smart table: `useTablePersonalisation="true"`

Using this however, when I click on action settings icon, 
[image]

It does not open any personalization box. Instead, it shows this error in console:

[image]

Debugging further, I found out that smart table do not have _oPersController property. 
[image]
**I do not why this is happening? How can I provide this propoerty to my smart table? Do I have to use any special tags for this in my VIEW/CONTROLLER file? Thanks a lot in advance.**

Comment: .openDialog is a method hanging off a Dialog. Are you sure this._oPersController is a Dialog instance?!

Comment: yes I am sure it's a dialog instance. In my other view files, where personalization is working, this._oPersController does exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table:customData>
            <core:CustomData key="p13nData" value='\{"columnKey": "PROJECT_DEFINITION" , "leadingProperty":"PROJECT_DEFINITION", "type":"string" \}'/>
        </table:customData>
```

Try above code, use key="p13nData" instead of p13nDialogSettings and pass the column key.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this thread is 5 years old, as I encountered the same problem I wanted to share my findings. This is in addition to the answer and snippet given by @Kishian Naicker (which is correct and should be used)

The _oPersController is created internally during smarttable initialization. My problem was, that we had created custom columns consisting of an hBox with a text and an image inside. While debugging I found the _oPersController maps the columns with getHeader().getText() to create the list of columns in the table (header is the default aggregation for column). But since our top level aggregation of the column was the hBox and hBox.getHeader.getText() returns undefined, the mapping failed and further the _oPersController never got created. I would say the main problem here was that it didn't throw any error or warning thus making it tedious to find the problem. I worked with UI5 vers. 1.118

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).